# Does a transaction occur in this case?

Tags: java, spring-transactions

Does a transaction occur in this case?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/student/z")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class someServiceController {
    
        @Autowired
        public OtherSomeService othService;
    
        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<?> someServiceControllers() {
            othService.Z();
            return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
        }

}

public class OtherSomeService {
    
    @Autowired
    private SomeService s;
    
    public SomeData Z() {
        s.A();
       
    }
}


public class SomeService {

    
    public SomeData A() {
        B();
       
    }

    
    @Transactional
    public SomeData B() {
        //some codes
       
    }

}
```

chatgpt4 says it was created, but when I try, there is no transaction manager in the logs. can you help me?

log is as follows

o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/v1/student/z

o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/student/z", parameters={}

s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.management.studentmanagement.controller.someServiceController#someServiceControllers()

o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor

o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]

o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing ["ok"]

o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor

o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK

Comment: `@Transactional` on `public SomeData B` is being ignored, since its being called from inside the same class. Anyhow, whether a transaction occured or not relies on the folloup code, which you've not provided. If you, for eg, you call Spring Repository further down the lane, then this repository is automatically wrapped in a transaction. But you shouldn't let Spring decide where to set the transaction boundaries, thus it's good advice to set `@Transactional` inside the service layer.